# Why when Jquery .on() event method is executed another .on() event in the same page is ALWAYS executed too

Tags: jquery

```
var $nav = $('.nav');
var $img = $('img');
$nav.on('click', function() {           
    //determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightNav')
        ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
    document.getElementById("pictureIndex").innerHTML = currentPosition + 1;                                    
    //hide/show controls
    manageNav(currentPosition);
    clearInterval(slideShowInterval);
    slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);
    moveSlide(slideWidth, currentPosition);
    console.log('end of nav function');
});

$img.on('click', function(){
    var path = traverseData(imgData,'path', $(this));
    window.location.assign("picturePage.html?name ="+path.name);
    return;
});
```

---

When the `$nav` event is called and its method executed, the second event is called but on `$nav` instead of on `$img` and off course it doesn't work because `$nav` can't be used for the `traverseData()` function. I tried everything but this happens every time! Please help me!

Comment: show a sample of the html that these click handlers apply to.

Comment: You need to provide more info--I copied/pasted this to jsfiddle, created an `<a>` with class of nav and an `<img>` and the img click handler does not fire when clicking the `<a>` link.

Comment: I also use .wrapAll, animate and setTimeOut if this is important.